# Selected Value need to be pass into the dropdown list angular material

Tags: angular

when i edit the data click the selected row on the table select row record successfully pass in to
form name and description on textbox but dropdown list but displayed
Selected Value need to be pass into the dropdown list Angular Material but it is not passing the value
what i tried so far I attached below.

this is design
task.component.html

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                            <mat-label>Complete</mat-label>
                            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="complete" name="complete">
                              <mat-option value="true">True</mat-option>
                              <mat-option value="false">False</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                          </mat-form-field>
                          
                          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                            <mat-label>Employee</mat-label>
                            <mat-select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="employeeId"   name="employeeId">
                              <mat-option *ngFor="let EmployeeItem of EmployeeArray" value="{{ EmployeeItem.employeeid}}">
                                {{ EmployeeItem.employeename }}
                            </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                          </mat-form-field>
```

**task.component.ts**

```
setUpdate(data:any)
{
     this.complete = data.complete;
     this.employeeId = data.employeeId;
 
}
```

here is the screen shot image
[image]

```
  getAllEmployees()
  {
    this.http.get("http://localhost:8075/api/v1/employee/getAllEmployees")
  .subscribe(
    (resultData: any) => {
      console.log(resultData);
      this.EmployeeArray = resultData;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching employee data:", error);
    }
  );

  }
```

Comment: please share stackblitz replicating the issue also please refine the question,  its not very clear what needs to be fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <mat-select (valueChange)="setUpdate($event)" matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="employeeId"   name="employeeId">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let EmployeeItem of EmployeeArray" value="{{ EmployeeItem.employeeid}}">
                            {{ EmployeeItem.employeename }}
                        </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>


setUpdate(data:any){
 this.complete = data.complete;
 this.employeeId = data.employeeId;
```

}

Comment: i checked your code sir. when i clecked the edit record on the row editable not select still into the drop down.

Comment: i added the screen shot image above please look at the image sir another data pass into  textboxs successfully

Comment: [(value)]="selectedCountry" 
use this instead of ngModel

Comment: still not working please provide me EmployeeArray

Comment: i added the array above please check it

Comment: have you use anydesk?

Comment: yes thanks i will give you my id wait

Comment: here :  731287857

Comment: live:.cid.62db83ddf2bc801a

Comment: skype id message me
i am not able to access your pc bro

Comment: teamviewer .........................

Comment: can you come to skyple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256316/discussion-between-codewithharshad-and-kobi-udemy).